# CosmosDB document client - how to implicit add type for query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using DocumentClient for Azure Cosmos DB in .NET Core 3.1. My example query is:

```
var results = await _cosmosClient
.CreateDocumentQuery<Employee>(_documentCollectionUri, FeedOptionsProvider.DefaultOptions<Employee>())
.Where(x => x.IdentityId == identityId)
.AsDocumentQuery()
.GetResponse();
```

This piece of code is quite problematic, because if there another one document in database with passing condition, but another type, then response will contain that object. I know that lambda expression is limited to public properties from generic type, but is there any possibility to implicit add checking type correctness? Database objects have property like `Discriminator` contains entity type, but there are no visible in lambda expression. My desired behaviour is check condition for this `Discriminator` property without having this property in object model. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method below that uses `QueryDefinition` Class and `container.GetItemQueryIterator` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Run a query (using Azure Cosmos DB SQL syntax) against the container
/// </summary>
private async Task QueryItemsAsync()
{
    var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Discriminator = 'Value' AND c.IdentityId = 'Id'";

    Console.WriteLine("Running query: {0}\n", sqlQueryText);

    QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
    FeedIterator<Family> queryResultSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Family>(queryDefinition);

    List<Family> families = new List<Family>();

    while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<Family> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (Family family in currentResultSet)
        {
            families.Add(family);
            Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}\n", family);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can directly add your query which will filter based on `Discriminator` field.

For more details on implementation, you can visit: [Tutorial: Build a .NET console app to manage data in Azure Cosmos DB SQL API account](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#Query)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your solution is not desired. I have a lot of repositories supported by ORM design and in each of them I have to querying without using SQL query. I would like to add this discriminator to query generated by LINQ expression using extension method or something like that. Is that possible?

Comment: Ohh, if that is the case, can you try adding `Discriminator` in `Employee` object and add the condition directly in the LINQ?

Comment: Also, pls mention in your question that you want to use this method because of business requirement.

Comment: I've mentioned that: My desired behaviour is check condition for this 'Discriminator' property without having this property in object model. So, I proposed usage of extension method as above, but it is not business requirement, only proposal if that is possible. I'm trying to avoid adding Discriminator property to Employee object, because I don't want to having property in domain object with name of its type.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this condition without adding it to the class.